# CMIS Sync ,Cron update

Tags: cron, nodes

Whenever I run cron , all the articles in drupal which I have edited/created get updated with the new timestamp(the time when cron runs) and the "updated" tag appears beside the article name.This happens again and again as I run cron,even if I did not make changes to that article again.
To be more precise : 
I edit two articles 1 ,2 today at 10:00 AM and run cron 5 min later at 10:05 , the time stamps of both are updated to 10:05 .
Again I edit article 1 at 10:10 and run cron at 10:20 and now, articles 1,2 have their time stamps at 10:20.
Any thoughts regarding this?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a module updating all of the nodes on each cron run using [`node_save`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_save/7), which updates the timestamp for the node when it's called. I'd try disabling the contributed/custom modules you have installed one-by-one until you find the culprit.

Comment: I think it is the cmis module.Inside `cmis_sync.cmis.inc`  the function `_cmis_sync_cmis_drupal_handle_updates` is the one that also has a `node_save` as you mentioned. I have already applied the patch at http://drupal.org/files/syncfixes-1291988.patch
Any thoughts?